# Select drives for installing a new container image

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, kubernetes

I have to spin up a k8s cluster from my host OS. The cluster roughly takes ~20GB space on my system. I have these partitions

```
df -khT
Filesystem                Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/RHEL7CSB-Root ext4       48G   32G   14G  70% /
devtmpfs                  devtmpfs  7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     tmpfs     7.6G  232M  7.4G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     tmpfs     7.6G  2.3M  7.6G   1% /run
tmpfs                     tmpfs     7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1            ext4      2.9G  192M  2.6G   7% /boot
/dev/mapper/RHEL7CSB-Home ext4       99G   45G   49G  48% /home
tmpfs                     tmpfs     1.6G   68K  1.6G   1% /run/user/114040
```

When I start docker command the containers start installing on `/dev/mapper/RHEL7CSB-Root` which eventually fills up quickly. Is there a way for me to select `/dev/mapper/RHEL7CSB-Home` for my installation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, what you want to know is how to store the docker containers in your `/home` directory instead of the default path, which is presumably elsewhere under `/`

Comment: Yes , this is my exact situation, is there any steps to configure the same?

Comment: This post appears to answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/50217666#50217666